# Cannot activate password auto-fill on iPhone 13 with iOS 15.5

Tags: iphone, ios, password, keychain

I just started using an iPhone 13 with iOS 15.5. I use Bitwarden as a password manager and I'd like to activate the auto-fill functionalities.

When I try to activate such functionalities, in **Settings** > **Passwords**, I cannot slide the auto-fill functionality on, and I also do not see any app in the list of the ones available for auto-fill (no Bitwarden, no Keychain, I even tried downloading a couple more password manager to see if they appeared in the list).

When going to **Settings** -> **Face ID & Passcode**, I noticed that the option "Use FaceId for:  --> Password Auto-fill" is activated, but greyed out, and I cannot modify it.

I tried looking online but apparently, this behaviour is not common. I tried turning the device on and off, deactivating FaceID, logging out of my iCloud account, but nothing seems to work so far.